# Remuxing a mkv video stream to mp4 on the fly

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

Is there any way to remux an mkv stream into an mp4 container on the fly?  I'm using an html5 `<video>` tag and while I know I won't get fantastic browser support, I'm building for the future (and this is part of a larger project where other features also require html5 compatible browsers).  It appears that there is better support for h.264 in an mp4 container than in the mkv container but some of my streams come in as mkv.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Mediacoder project](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm). It is a transcoder with a GUI frontend to various **major media-related open source projects**. It supports **all major Operating System**.

Additionally Mediacoder supports a web-User interface, which may be ideally suited to your web-related project.

There has been an [issue with mkv](http://forum.mediacoderhq.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11378) in the past, but that should be solved by now.

Comment: It looks like it only runs on Linux under Wine... It's definitely a cool project but I don't think it will serve our purpose. Still, +1 for interesting info.

Answer (score 1):

Remuxing MKV into MP4 is one of the tasks performed by [ps3mediaserver](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/); since it does a lot of extraneous tasks, I'm not sure it is where I would recommend starting but I think it might be a suitable last-ditch effort.

I've used [`mkvextract`](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html) to extract tracks from MKV files and [`MP4Box`](http://gpac.wp.institut-telecom.fr/mp4box/) to re-package the data into MP4 streams.

I always ran the programs in a batch mode, rather than streaming mode, because I only wanted to burn the CPU cycles for the conversion *once*, so our uses are different. (I don't know if both formats allow for streaming conversion.) But perhaps these two tools can allow you to build something close enough to streaming.

Comment: isn't ps3mediaserver to allow your ps3 to access other media on your network?

Comment: Yes, but UPnP is just a handful of HTTP responses and replies and won't be so deeply integrated into the rest of the product that it is useless.

Comment: What I was kind of getting at was, you install it on your Mac/PC, where all the files are located, and it remuxes them on the way out.  I have a stream incoming and outgoing.

Comment: Sure; and ps3mediaserver is _probably_ built on underlying tools that can handle streaming content fine. Don't let the pretty GUI distract you from the core of the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

VideoLan Server can do remuxing on the fly. Look here
http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html